# SHIRK kuffer in games Please answer this

Tags: shirk, kufr

I made a mistake by playing a video game long ago named 'The You testament' which has so many shirk elements like magic soccery and  like mediation to gain power and and perform soccery and story of Jesus  according to Christianity and i didn't give any attention to it i just played for fun and i didn't take  seriously  and unintentionally without realising that it is sin.

Now i realised it was completely Prohibited. So my question is did i commited shirk as i didn't know then,(now Alhamdulillah I'm a practicing muslim) and i was recently watching video games in Islam i then realised it.

Please answer me as i didn't know it was shirk or kuffer .Please it's important I'm worried.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think it's obvious that you should try to avoid playing religious games about another religions (if you don't want to worry about your own religion after, like you're doing it now).

Now about your question, my opinion is that it's only a game therefore it's not a shirk/qufr for a reason that you just didn't know about it and didn't change your believes while playing the game. For example, if the person plays the game with greek "gods" in it, it doesn't mean he starts to believe in them, but obviously it's better to try to avoid these type of games. Obviously, there's no direct hadith or ayat for referencing here just because games weren't invented in the times of the Prophet (p.b.u.h), so I can only suggest you to make a dua and say shahada in case you're still worried about it, and try to avoid games about another religions (it's actually funny why were you even playing christian android game from 2008).

UPD: With quick google search I found that there's actually a [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/243131/ruling-on-playing-a-game-in-which-the-story-has-to-do-with-a-meteor-that-falls-to-earth-and-brings-the-dead-back-to-life) that agrees with what I said